# how to convert a jpg image to pgm format in cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, pgm

I want to covert a .jpg image to a .pgm image.The image is being obtained from a tcp socket which has live streaming by a OPENCV program.
In matlab I used the imread function to do it. How do I do it in cpp?
I am working in linux platform.  Is there any function to do it in OPENCV?

can anyone help?

regards,
shiksha

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

In OpenCV, you can use [**`imread()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) to load the JPG image, and then use [**`imwrite()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) it to the PGM image (by using the `CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY` format flag).

Answer (score 2):

please look at OpenCV documentation for HighGui library functions `cv::imread` and `cv::imwrite`.
Read the jpg using `cv::imread` and resave it with `cv::imsave` using filename with proper extension.

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread
- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite